# What is the compound noun of a box that contains new toys

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm really confused, I'd like to make a compound noun for a **box** that **contains new toys** only. Should I name it "New toy box"? but, this makes me think of a new box for toys not a **box for new toys**.

**[ Questions ]**

What is the correct noun ? and is there some rules to follow when forming this type of compound nouns?

Comment: You already know how to describe this thing — it's a *box of new toys*. That's what I think most English speakers would call it. Why do you want a compound noun for it?

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterShor for the comment, so a "box of new toys" is the only way to refer to this kind of boxes.

Comment: You could call it a *new-toy box*, but I think you'd probably only ever do that to demonstrate why you sometimes need hyphens in compound nouns.

Comment: @PeterShor the dash changes the whole meaning, AWESOME, I think this could be   a great answer +1

Comment: @PeterShor thanks a billion :-D https://english.stackexchange.com/a/499740/250862

Comment: The compound noun "**new-toy** box" as opposed to "**old-toy** box" is fine (my box for new toys / old toys).

Comment: @BillJ Thanks a lot, I corrected my question ( **for** not **of**, right? )

Comment: @CryptoBird A box for toys is a box you keep in the house for the purpose of storing toys. A box of toys is a box which is filled with toys. Both are correct, but mean different things.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet you are AWESOME, thank you :-D +1

Comment: @KannE is that possible ? I mean, I didn't know that I could use plural, is it common to use the plural in compound nouns ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PeterShor, the compound noun of a box that contains new toys is :

> **A new-toy box**

According to [oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen#hyphens_in_compound_words), hyphens could be used to show that there is a relationship between the words that make up a compound noun.

Comment: *the compound noun of a box that contains new toys is*  No, as the stream of comments should make clear a box that contains new toys is *a box of new toys*.  *new-toy box* is an example of how to make new meanings with hyphens, it's a morphological exemplar.  If it has ever been seen in the wild I'll eat my hat.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks for your great comment. I meant with a box that contains new toys, a storage box that contains brand new toys (maybe, a few boxes of them), but I guess this expression doesn't sound natural. +1

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Maybe, a box that contains a few boxes of brand new toys